# Database Design for University Courses

Tags: database-design

I am currently designing a database for a university (assignment!). Everything looks to be okay. However, I ran into a subtle issue.

Now, I have `Intake` entity which holds information about the intake that students can register in. Every intake has a number of `Specialism`s, and each specialism has a number of `Module`s to be lectured, and every module has a number of `Lecturer`s to deliver it.

The illustration below should clear the design (The intermediate entities are for tackling many-to-many relationships).

[image: Database Logical Design]

Now, say I have an intake code that is `F1205` (Full-time intake beginning in May 2012) that opens only (for the sake of simplicity) for one specialism (say, `SE` for Software Engineering). The specialized intake for this specialism would be a concatenated key `F1205SE`. From this id, I can tell what are the modules to be lectured by using the `SE` portion of it.

Because a module can be lectured by many lecturers, how can I specify the lecturer who will be delivering the module in that specific specialized intake, and where to store this information?

I feel that I have a design error, but I don't know where.

Comment: From what I can make of the question you'll need a table between the intake and module lecturers to record which lecturer is allocated. But in general many to many on tables like you have above on module lecturers and the specialism modules table is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you saying that a module will be taught by a different lecturer depending on what specialism it's being catered to?  For example, if students from the "Computer Science" intake took the module "Robotics," they'd be taught by Alice, but if "Electrical Engineering" students took "Robotics," they'd be taught by Bob?

Comment: @XavierHolt No. It can be Alice or Bob teaching in both.